# Python 3 & Tkinter buggy and slow

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

So, a few months back I made a small GUI for handling NPCs in a roleplaying campaign I was running. I haven't touched in since then, except that now I need it! Tomorrow, in fact...

I have a few odd error... Loading the GUI seems to work fine, but when I start to press buttons the troubles start. It seemed, at first, that it the script was very slow, which it shouldn't be, calling a two line dice function on a button press. I accidentally figured out that when I hover the mouse over the "close/minimize window" buttons (not in the GUI, but in the OS), the button would update with the result of the button press.

The same thing happens with a listbox I have: choosing an item may or may not select the item straight away (but hovering over the close/minimize updates it), and the results of the selection may or may not show. The results is in fact weirder: selecting a listbox item is supposed to get info from the selected item and print it in another frame. Even if the selection itself is fine without hovering, the printed text is somehow "clipped", showing only an area seeming to cover an arbitrarily sized square of text... Remedied by hovering, of course. The rest of the GUI have the exact same problems.

I have no clue what is going on here. The script was written on another computer, but that was also a Mac running the same OSX version (Mavericks), and it was a MUCH slower computer. This script shouldn't need any sort of advanced specs, though! I'm guessing it's something wrong with migrating to the new computer and the various version of different software? I'll paste the script down below, in case that'll help somehow.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, especially if it comes before the next epic campaign of Superheroes starts tomorrow afternoon! =P

[UPDATE]:

It was some time ago, but I still would like to have this problem solved. I've reduced my script to just a simple button, and the problem persists: clicking the button, even though there is no function or anything associated with it, only results in the frozen "button-clicked"-colour (i.e. light blue on OSX Yosemite), and I have to hover my mouse pointer over the close/minimize/etc. buttons in the top left corner to make it go back to "idle-button"-colour (i.e. grey).

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

test = tk.Button(root, text='test')
test.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

So, the problem obviously isn't with any of my "downstream" scripting, but something with the module or my way of calling it. Calling the script for the Terminal doesn't give me any error messages, and the problem is still there. Any ideas? It would be really, *really* good to get to the bottom of this problem!

Comment: Run it in terminal and add to question all (full) error messages you get.

Comment: Never ran a python script from the terminal before, so I made an alias for my anaconda installation in .bash_profile (as per http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20364700/using-two-different-python-distributions) and executed the script. No errors, but same weirdness as before. =/

Comment: I have updated the question with new/less code, and the problem persists.

Comment: "So, the problem obviously isn't with any of my "downstream" scripting, but something with the module or my way of calling it." So, how exactly _are_ you calling it? What's your exact Python version, and how do you start the scrip?

Comment: I've used both PyCharm (an IDE) and the OSX Terminal. Calling it from PyCharm is just to `run` it, and from the Terminal I just use `./test.py`. I have Python v 3.4.1, from an Anaconda build.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem when using Tk 8.5.13 on Mac OS X Sierra (10.12.3) with Python and IDLE v3.6.0.
Upgrading to TCL/Tk 8.5.18.0 as recommended on the Python Software Foundation page https://www.python.org/download/mac/tcltk/#activetcl-8-5-18-0 seemed to do the trick. This was the recommended version for my edition of the OS.
The interface I was building starting responding as I would expect, i.e. straight away when one of the controls was used. The only reservation I have so far is that normal buttons don't seem to have any sort of animation now, although the buttons do actually work. 
-S.

Comment: Thanks, that did it! Seems like it was different versions spooking about...