# Plotting with tkinter slows and crashes on newer Macs

Tags: python, macos, performance, matplotlib, tkinter

I have encountered that on some newer Mac machines, `matplotlib` plotting in `tkinter` is significantly slower than on Windows or even other older Mac machines.

Here is a script that reproduces the issue.  Every the button is clicked, a new random series of 1000 points is plotted 10 times, and it prints the time to draw them:

```
import time
import tkinter as tk
import matplotlib as mpl
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import (
    FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2Tk)

n = 1000

class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super(App, self).__init__()
        self.main_frame = tk.Frame(self,)
        self.main_frame.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1)

        self.plot1_button = tk.Button(self.main_frame, text='Plot 1',
                                      command=self.draw_plot1)
        self.plot1_button.pack(fill=tk.X,expand=1)

        self.FIG = mpl.figure.Figure()
        self.AX = self.FIG.add_subplot()
        self.canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(self.FIG, master=self.main_frame)
        self.canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1)
        self.toolbar = NavigationToolbar2Tk(self.canvas, self.main_frame)
        self.canvas._tkcanvas.pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1)

    def draw_plot1(self):
        colors = ['red', 'orange', 'yellow', 'green', 'blue',
                  'indigo', 'violet', 'black', 'purple', 'gold']
        start = time.time()
        for i in range(10):
            self.AX.clear()
            self.AX.plot(range(n), np.random.rand(n), color=colors[i])
            self.canvas.draw_idle()
            self.toolbar.update()
            self.update()
        end = time.time()
        print(end - start)

root = App()
root.mainloop()
```

I've found that the size of the `tkinter` window has a large effect on the efficiency.  On my Windows desktop (a mid-to-low level gaming PC), the graphs are drawn in under a second, even with the window maximally expanded.  On a 2013 MacBook Air, it is slower at about 1.2-1.5 seconds with a large window size, but the program still looks and feels responsive.

But on two separate 2019 MacBook Pro laptops that I've tested, expanding the window below full screen size can cause the program to take multiple seconds, and it starts to feel sluggish.  Some graphs remain on the screen for seconds themselves.  Moreover, at full screen size, the program eventually crashes or stops plotting (or the entire program is taking minutes to complete).  On closing the program I get errors like:

```
_tkinter.TclError: invalid command name "pyimage150"

#or

_tkinter.TclError: can't invoke "update" command: application has been destroyed
```

This example captures an issue I've encountered in a graphing program I created, which for now has just made the program feel slow and causes transient plotting errors (usually with less points being plotted).  But I worry it could lead to crashes and render the program unusable.

I don't really know what specific components could be related to this problem, so I have left out specific specs.  But I can say that in terms of CPU and graphics, it seems to go like MacBook Air < MacBook Pro < Windows desktop, even though the performance is like MacBook Pro <<< MacBook Air < Windows desktop (I'm happy to include some specs if that would help).

I have tried to add additional [`update` or `update_idletasks` calls](http://effbot.org/zone/tkinter-performance.htm) here and there, but have not found anything producing an effect.  I have seen [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42205075/13386979) about updating Tcl/Tk, which I have done (it also seems like as of Python 3.7 [this shouldn't matter](https://www.python.org/download/mac/tcltk/#activetcl-8-5-18-0)).

My two theories were that either the increased resolution on the newer Mac is causing it to be a more expensive operation (not sure if that makes any sense?) or that it is just an OS problem (the earlier laptop is on Yosemite while the newer is on Catalina).  The latter is what I am fearing.  But either way, currently, I am stumped for things to try.  If anyone has any input, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: It sounds like a GPU issue but the OS would factor into it as well

Comment: FWIW: `1.5 - 1.6` seconds on a 2011 i5 2 cores macbook air with `Sierra 10.12.6` - this increases to `2.2 - 2.3` when window is maximized.

Comment: So what's your `print(tk.TkVersion)` and python version right now? I achieve results similar to what @ReblochonMasque posted.

Comment: @Evorage I agree.  I am not so familiar with these graphics cards, but the Macbook Air (successfully runs the program) on Intel HD Graphics 5000 1536 MB, while the newer laptop graphics (which fail to run the program) are AMD Radeon Pro 5500M 4GB + Intel UHD Graphics 630 1536MB.

Comment: @ReblochonMasque Thanks for that information!  That sounds acceptable provided the program is not crashing

Comment: @Asmus `tk` is 8.6, Python is 3.8.3.  Thanks for testing