# Use Python distribution other than Anaconda

Tags: python, windows, anaconda, python-3.5

I'm struggling with Anaconda Python distribution. I installed it first months ago, but now I need to use TensorFlow which is not officially supported (and updated) within the Anaconda distribution.

I installed then a new Python distribution (Python-3.5) and tried to use it, instead of Anaconda, to run the above mentioned library. I have some issues though 'cause the Conda has set as default Python distribution its own one.

I saw in this discussion [Using two different python distributions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20364700/using-two-different-python-distributions) that my goal could be achieved by setting an alias like '***pyconda='/path/to/your/anaconda/bin/python'***' in my ***.bash_profile file***.

The problem is that I have no such a file under my home (and I tried to insert a brand new one and run simple aliases like '*alias cd="cd /c"*' to see if it could work but it does not).

Could someone please give me an hint?
Thx in advance to all of you!

Comment: Which operating system are you using? Please edit your question and add it as a tag.

Comment: Hi, I'm actually using Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

For Anaconda, my best suggestion, if not already tried, would be to use their graphical installer.

For TensorFlow installation, I would recommend using Pip

Hope this helps !

Comment: Hi, thx for the hint! I tried first to install TensorFlow with pip, but the 'conda' installed pip tried to take over the Python 3.5 pip version I actually wanted to use. I installed then TF within my project "Settings" (I'm using PyCharm) using the install-packages wizard.